# Can't make Validator interface to work on template-driven Angular 2 custom component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a domain model for bank account:

`export interface BankAccount { acc1: string, acc2: string, acc3: string, acc4: string }`

Parent form is template-driven, captures name and bank account number.
To capture bank account number which is comprised of 4 parts digits, I managed to write a custom form control component in model-driven way. It implements ControlValueAccessor and Validator interfaces so, on a parent form, its value/valid works perfect.

Now I tried to write another bank account component in template-driven way. So far its ControlValueAccessor interface seems working but I couldn't make its Validator interface to work.

The problem is: In account 1, its value is emitted ok to parent form and validated each time I types in any number. But in account 2, the value is emitted ok but for some reason, validate() method is not being called???

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QETk5C8Yb6JyyWvEL2bM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second component you have to fire `propagateChange` method manually to invoke the validation.

**Template**

```
<input type="text" name="acc1" [ngModel]="accountNumber.acc1"
    (ngModelChange)="change('acc1', $event)"/>
```

or

```
<input *ngFor="let prop of ['acc1', 'acc2', 'acc3', 'acc4']" type="text" 
   name="{{prop}}" [ngModel]="accountNumber[prop]" 
          (ngModelChange)="change(prop, $event)"/>
```

**Component**

```
change(prop, val) {
  this.accountNumber[prop] = val; 
  this.propagateChange(this.accountNumber);
}
```

> Note: i fixed your typo in `propogateChange` method

Updated **[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pnM4W3KSrs9e2FgKZ16X?p=preview)**

See also a great article about it:

- **[Custom Form Controls in Angular 2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html)**

Comment: Thanks it works, template-driven way seems to require extra works whereas model-driven way is just doing "this.accountNumber.valueChanges.subscribe(fn)"..